# echo in the leaderboard

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a leader board with codes below:

```css
/*--------------------
Body
--------------------*/
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 450px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;  
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  
}


/*--------------------
Leaderboard
--------------------*/
.leaderboard {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 285px;
  height: 308px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3a404d, #181c26);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 30px rgba(62, 9, 11, .3);

  h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #e1e1e1;
    padding: 12px 13px 18px;

    & svg {
      width: 25px;
      height: 26px;
      position: relative;
      top: 3px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      vertical-align: baseline;
    }

  }

  ol {
    counter-reset: leaderboard;

    li {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      font-size: 14px;
      counter-increment: leaderboard;
      padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);


      &::before {
        content: counter(leaderboard);
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 15px;
        left: 15px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: #c24448;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 20px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      mark {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
        margin: 0;
        background: none;
        color: #fff;

        &::before, &::after {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 1;
          bottom: -11px;
          left: -9px;
          border-top: 10px solid #c24448;
          border-left: 10px solid transparent;
          transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
          opacity: 0;
        }

        &::after {
          left: auto;
          right: -9px;
          border-left: none;
          border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        }
      }

      small {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
      }

      &::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #fa6855;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
        // transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
        transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        opacity: 0;
      }

      &:nth-child(1) {
        background: #fa6855;
        &::after {
          background: #fa6855;
        }
      }

      &:nth-child(2) {
        background: #e0574f;
        &::after {
          background: #e0574f;
          box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
        }

        & mark {
          &::before, &::after {
            border-top: 6px solid #ba4741;
            bottom: -7px;
          }
        }
      }

      &:nth-child(3) {
        background: #d7514d;
        &::after {
          background: #d7514d;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .11);
        }

        & mark {
          &::before, &::after {
            border-top: 2px solid #b0433f;
            bottom: -3px;
          }
        }
      }

      &:nth-child(4) {
        background: #cd4b4b;
        &::after {
          background: #cd4b4b;
          box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        }

        & mark {
          &::before, &::after {
            top: -7px;
            bottom: auto;
            border-top: none;
            border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;;
          }
        }
      }

      &:nth-child(5) {
        background: #c24448;
        border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        &::after {
          background: #c24448;
          box-shadow: 0 -2.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
          border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        }

        & mark {
          &::before, &::after {
            top: -9px;
            bottom: auto;
            border-top: none;
            border-bottom: 8px solid #993639;
          }
        }
      }

    }

    // hover
    li:hover {
      z-index: 2;
      overflow: visible;

      &::after {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
      }

      & mark {
        &::before, &::after {
          opacity: 1;
          transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
        }
      }
    }

  }
}

* {
  //display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="leaderboard">
  <h1>
    <svg class="ico-cup">
      <use xlink:href="#cup"></use>
    </svg>
    Most active Players
  </h1>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <mark>Jerry Wood</mark>
      <small>315</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Brandon Barnes</mark>
      <small>301</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Raymond Knight</mark>
      <small>292</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
      <small>245</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
      <small>203</small>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>


<svg style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="cup" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="25px" height="26px" viewBox="0 0 25 26" enable-background="new 0 0 25 26" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#F26856" d="M21.215,1.428c-0.744,0-1.438,0.213-2.024,0.579V0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865H6.69
 C6.204,0,5.81,0.387,5.81,0.865v1.142C5.224,1.641,4.53,1.428,3.785,1.428C1.698,1.428,0,3.097,0,5.148
 C0,7.2,1.698,8.869,3.785,8.869h1.453c0.315,0,0.572,0.252,0.572,0.562c0,0.311-0.257,0.563-0.572,0.563
 c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865c0.421,0,0.816-0.111,1.158-0.303
 c0.318,0.865,0.761,1.647,1.318,2.31c0.686,0.814,1.515,1.425,2.433,1.808c-0.04,0.487-0.154,1.349-0.481,2.191
 c-0.591,1.519-1.564,2.257-2.975,2.257H5.238c-0.486,0-0.88,0.388-0.88,0.865v4.283c0,0.478,0.395,0.865,0.88,0.865h14.525
 c0.485,0,0.88-0.388,0.88-0.865v-4.283c0-0.478-0.395-0.865-0.88-0.865h-1.452c-1.411,0-2.385-0.738-2.975-2.257
 c-0.328-0.843-0.441-1.704-0.482-2.191c0.918-0.383,1.748-0.993,2.434-1.808c0.557-0.663,1-1.445,1.318-2.31
 c0.342,0.192,0.736,0.303,1.157,0.303c0.486,0,0.88-0.387,0.88-0.865c0-0.478-0.394-0.865-0.88-0.865
 c-0.315,0-0.572-0.252-0.572-0.563c0-0.31,0.257-0.562,0.572-0.562h1.452C23.303,8.869,25,7.2,25,5.148
 C25,3.097,23.303,1.428,21.215,1.428z M5.238,7.138H3.785c-1.116,0-2.024-0.893-2.024-1.99c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99
 c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99v2.06C5.627,7.163,5.435,7.138,5.238,7.138z M18.883,21.717v2.553H6.118v-2.553H18.883
 L18.883,21.717z M13.673,18.301c0.248,0.65,0.566,1.214,0.947,1.686h-4.24c0.381-0.472,0.699-1.035,0.947-1.686
 c0.33-0.865,0.479-1.723,0.545-2.327c0.207,0.021,0.416,0.033,0.627,0.033c0.211,0,0.42-0.013,0.627-0.033
 C13.195,16.578,13.344,17.436,13.673,18.301z M12.5,14.276c-2.856,0-4.93-2.638-4.93-6.273V1.73h9.859v6.273
 C17.43,11.638,15.357,14.276,12.5,14.276z M21.215,7.138h-1.452c-0.197,0-0.39,0.024-0.572,0.07v-2.06
 c0-1.097,0.908-1.99,2.024-1.99c1.117,0,2.025,0.893,2.025,1.99C23.241,6.246,22.333,7.138,21.215,7.138z"/>
      </symbol>
</svg>
```

I have written the php and through a query retrieved the top 10 performers.

I have fetched the query result in a variable.Now I want to echo the variable of top 10 in the above leaderboard.

In the html its an ordered list .**Where exactly to echo the variable  storing top10 .**

What to change in the html ,if any?

Kindly help.

Comment: You just want to simply echo them from PHP variable?

Comment: yeah,just echo the variable which contains the top10 result

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the result, something like this:

```
<ol>
<?php foreach ($leaderboard as $key => $value) {?>
<li>
  <mark><?php echo $value['name']?></mark>
  <small><?php echo $value['score']?></small>
</li>
<?php }?>
</ol>
```

this is just an example. I don`t know the structure of your data. If you provide us the data returned from the query it will be better.

Other variant that will achieve having only one simple echo in the html (little ugly but working) will be:

```
<?php
$leaderboardHtml = '';
foreach ($leaderboard as $key => $value) {
    $leaderboardHtml .= '
    <li>
        <mark>'.$value['name'].'</mark>
        <small>'.$value['score'].'</small>
    </li>';
}
?>

<ol>
<?php echo $leaderboardHtml;?>
</ol>
```

Comment: I have a variable fetching top10 performers and I just want to echo that only.echo once,should give me the result in the page.I dont want to echo separately for separate members as u are saying

Comment: You must use foreach (or another loop) or you will need to write very long echo statement. Belive me, this one shown by krasipenkov is good.